# applescript to move 2 kinds of files to different folders

Tags: applescript

Hi, I'm trying to create an Applescript to do the following:

Over the week a have several jpg and eps files on my hard drive. I have two folders: Vector and Images.
After some few days I get a few dozens of this mixed files which I have to manually select and move to its respective folder.

How can I move the .eps to the VECTOR folder and the jpg to IMAGES folder.
 I don´t know anything about applescripting, so I copied parts of other scripts and put this together:

on run {input, parameters} -- copy

```
if theExtension is "eps" then
    set destination to ~/user/Desktop/VECTO
end if
    tell application "Finder"
        move anItem to destination
if theExtension is "jpg" then
    set destination to ~/user/Desktop/IMAGO
end if
    tell application "Finder"
        move anItem to destination
```

end run

Of course it is wrong, but wish someone could help me put this straight
Thnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are incorporating this into an Automator workflow from the way the question is phrased.

```
on run {input, parameters} -- copy
    repeat with aFile in input
        tell application "Finder"
            if name extension of aFile is "eps" then
                move aFile to folder ((path to desktop as text) & "VECTO")
            else if name extension of aFile is "jpg" then
                move aFile to folder ((path to desktop as text) & "IMAGO")
            end if
        end tell
    end repeat 
end run
```

If not you can use:

```
set myFiles to (choose file with multiple selections allowed)
repeat with aFile in myFiles
    tell application "Finder"
        if name extension of aFile is "eps" then
            move aFile to folder ((path to desktop as text) & "VECTO")
        else if name extension of aFile is "jpg" then
            move aFile to folder ((path to desktop as text) & "IMAGO")
        end if
    end tell
end repeat
```

Comment: The first one works perfect!. Now a second question, I have a NAS drive in which I have the same name's folder for back up. How can I make this script to copy the file directly to a NAS drive?